# ModuleClient IoT Hub Edge device: How to receive messages from device queue?

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub

We deploy IoT Edge Modules to our devices and can send messages to IoT Hub or execute direct methods. ModuleClient however also has a few methods (such as CompleteAsync) to delete a message from the device queue.

Q: Is there any way to receive device queue messages directly in the module? Either by routing rules, use of a ModuleClient method or possibly even by using a DeviceClient instance within a Module?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Only direct methods are supported with IoT Edge modules. there is [sort of a workaround](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/205) but I would actually not recommend exposing config.yaml to a module.